# Plotting the Energies of the Perturbed Hamiltonian in the Two-state Quantum System

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, two-level-system

I would like to understand the following Figure, taken from the [German Wikipedia site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Qm_tnenergy1.png):

[image]

First of all, [the German Wikipedia site](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zweizustandssystem) denotes as $E_{\pm}$ the energies of the new Hamiltonian $H = H^{0} + W$. As one can calculate, these are given as $E_{\pm} = E_m \pm \sqrt{\Delta^2 + \left| W_{12}\right|^2}$. $E_{1}$ and $E_{2}$ denote the eigenvalues of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H^{0}$.

(i) If I plot $E_{\pm}$ versus $\Delta$, then I have the term $E_m = \frac{E_1 + E_2}{2}$, which Wikipedia simply ignores when drawing. Is that an error? Because at $\Delta = 0$, we have $E_{\pm} = E_m \pm \left| W_{12}\right|$.

(ii) This question is related to (i): For $\Delta = 0$, $E_1 = 2\Delta + E_2 = E_2$ (simply because $\Delta = \frac{E_1 - E_2}{2}$). But who says that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are both $0$ at $\Delta = 0$, is this a choice?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks Jakob, I edited my post!

Comment: Actually, now it got clearer to me (seeing that in the script, they write $E_m$ instead of $0$ for the unperturbed energies at $\Delta = 0$). I made an edit suggestion, where I added one line, because that I am missing right now. I would have one additional question, if that's okay: How can I draw $E_1$ versus $\Delta$, because $E_1 = 2\Delta + E_2$, what do I do with $E_2$?

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Oh my, it's actually quite easy, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find lecture notes of the author of the Wikipedia picture, in which he included an additional figure where you can find $E_m$ in the plot (p. 56):

http://www.jkrieger.de/download/quantenmechanik.pdf

Also, note that at $\Delta = 0$, $E_1 = E_2$, because by definition $\Delta = \frac{E_1 - E_2}{2}$.

**Edit**: Regarding your comment: From the definitions $2\, E_m \equiv E_1+ E_2$ and $2\,\Delta \equiv E_1-E_2$ it follows that $E_1 = E_m + \Delta$ and $E_2 = E_m -\Delta$, which should match the plot in the script and Wikipedia

Comment: Yes, Wikipedia draws the energies as a function of $\Delta = (E_1 - E_2)/2$, thanks for your answer.

Comment: @MathIsFun : Please also have a look at [this Wikipedia page and the explanation therein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avoided_crossing).